.NET Core T4 Templates - The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced
I've got a solution with different projects (Class Libraries with .NET Core 6.0) which all use T4 templates for different code generation purposes. What I'd like to do is put commonly used code (e.g. for data access) in a separate project and call it from the different T4 templates by referencing the assemblies using the following T4 directives:
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)\myCommonProject.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="myCommonProject" #>

Trying this I encounter the following error:
Compiling transformation: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. [Namespace / Path to DLL]

My projects containing the templates are all based on .NET Core 6.0. What I've tried so far is creating the common project with .NET Core 6.0 and .NET Standard 2.1. Both result in the above error. The only way making the common project work is if I use .NET Framework 4.8 (I assume that all other .NET Framework version would work the same).
Is it not possible to make it work using all .NET Core 6.0 class libraries?
Help is greatly appreciated.
